# Eigenvalues of a 2x2 stochastic Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices

In one of my lecture notes it is stated that one of the Eigenvalues (EV) of a stochastic Matrix can be calculated by $P_{11} - P_{21}$

I.e I have the following matrix :
$$\begin{matrix} 
    0.1 & 0.9 \\
    0.5 & 0.5 \\
\end{matrix}$$
Obviously the EV are 1 and -0.4

Okay lets look at some more random Numbers :
$$\begin{matrix} 
    0.42653 & 0.57347 \\
    0.2956 & 0.7044 \\
\end{matrix}$$   $P_{11} - P_{21}$ = 0.42653 - 0.2956 = 0.13093 which is its EV. The other is obviously 1

Is that always right for these kind of stochastic matrices?

Answer (score 3):

When $P$ is a $2\times2$ row-stochastic matrix, one of its eigenvalues is $1$. Let the other eigenvalue be $\lambda$. Then
$$
\lambda+1=\operatorname{tr}(P)=p_{11}+p_{22}=p_{11}+(1-p_{21}).
$$
Therefore $\lambda=p_{11}-p_{21}$.

Alternatively, let
$$
P=\pmatrix{p_{11}&p_{12}\\ p_{21}&p_{22}}=\pmatrix{a&1-a\\ b&1-b}.
$$
Then
$$
\pmatrix{1&-1}P=\pmatrix{1&-1}\pmatrix{a&1-a\\ b&1-b}=(a-b)\pmatrix{1&-1}.
$$
Therefore $a-b=p_{11}-p_{21}=p_{22}-p_{12}$ is an eigenvalue of $P$.